# joins to combine multiple de-duping strategies

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a dataset that I'm trying to clean up and deduplicate two ways, at the same time.

For example - if we ignore punctuation (including spaces), word order, and abbreviations, these company names are all the same:

```sql
 company_id |    company_name    |        words        | words_wo_spaces |    words_sorted     | sorted_words_wo_spaces 
------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------------
         17 | the usa co         | {THE,USA,COMPANY}   | THEUSACOMPANY   | {COMPANY,THE,USA}   | COMPANYTHEUSA     
         18 | the u s a company  | {THE,U,S,A,COMPANY} | THEUSACOMPANY   | {A,COMPANY,S,THE,U} | ACOMPANYSTHEU     
         19 | usa company, the   | {USA,COMPANY,THE}   | USACOMPANYTHE   | {COMPANY,THE,USA}   | COMPANYTHEUSA     
         20 | u s a company, the | {U,S,A,COMPANY,THE} | USACOMPANYTHE   | {A,COMPANY,S,THE,U} | ACOMPANYSTHEU
```

I have some helper functions working to create all the columns aside from `company_id` and `company_name` - functions to split & sort words and to re-code words to remove common abbreviations (replace 'co' with 'company', for example). I'm leaving those helper functions out of this question.

If we look at the columns `words_wo_spaces`, there are two pairs of matching companies: `17`/`18` and `19`/`20`.
If we group by `sorted_words_wo_spaces`, there are two different pairs of matching companies: `17`/`19` and `18`/`20`.

What I really want is a query (or two or three) that can use both methods of grouping companies to determine that they are all the same.

Query 1

```sql
SELECT 
  array_agg(company_id) ids
  , array_agg(company_name) names
FROM companies
GROUP BY words_wo_spaces

-- Returns

--    ids   | words_wo_spaces 
-- ---------+-----------------
--  {19,20} | USACOMPANYTHE
--  {17,18} | THEUSACOMPANY
```

Query 2

```sql
SELECT 
  array_agg(company_id) ids
  , array_agg(company_name) names
FROM companies
GROUP BY sorted_words_wo_spaces

-- Returns

--    ids   | sorted_words_wo_spaces 
-- ---------+------------------------
--  {18,20} | ACOMPANYSTHEU
--  {17,19} | COMPANYTHEUSA
```

But I cannot figure out how to combine the two. If 17=18 and 18=20 and 17=19, then they're all the same. Is it possible to put this logic into a sql query?

I did try joining the results of those two queries, but that was unhelpful (as expected, once I worked it out).

```sql
WITH
  unsorted_groups AS <query 1>
  , sorted_groups AS <query 2>
SELECT 
  array_cat(sorted_groups.ids, unsorted_groups.ids) ids
FROM sorted_groups 
JOIN unsorted_groups 
  ON unsorted_groups.ids && sorted_groups.ids;

-- Returns

--      ids   
-- ---------------
--  {18,20,19,20}
--  {18,20,17,18}
--  {17,19,19,20}
--  {17,19,17,18}
```

What *would* be helpful is a query that would return a table like this, so that the arrays of ids could be sorted & then used to group all rows into one (this ideal result has each id in the `ids` array of each row).

```sql
--      ids   
-- ---------------
--  {18,17,19,20}
--  {18,20,17,19}
--  {17,19,18,20}
--  {17,19,20,18}
```

Comment: there are similarity and levenshtein functions available e.g. see arctype.com/blog/postgres-fuzzy-search also you may want to consider removing common stopwords etc. see: https://dbfiddle.uk/5wXi9V82  and/or using full text indexing: stackoverflow.com/questions/42052173/…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join the two queries using the `overlap operator &&` as the following:

```
WITH Q1 AS
(
  SELECT 
    array_agg(company_id ORDER BY company_id) ids -- The order by is necessary for the aggregation in the joined query
  FROM companies
  GROUP BY words_wo_spaces
),
Q2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    array_agg(company_id ORDER BY company_id) ids -- The order by is necessary
  FROM companies
  GROUP BY sorted_words_wo_spaces
),
Joined_Q AS
(
  SELECT Q1.ids Q1_ids,
         UNNEST(Q2.ids) Q2_ids -- for each array of ids from q1, unnest the matched array of ids from q2
  FROM Q1 JOIN Q2
  ON Q1.ids && Q2.ids
)
SELECT DISTINCT ARRAY_AGG(Q2_ids ORDER BY Q2_ids) -- aggregate the unnested q2 ids as a single array.
FROM Joined_Q
GROUP BY Q1_ids
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZwbvhM-e)

Comment: Fantastic; exactly what I needed! I think the `ORDER BY` statements aren't necessary (I tried with & without).
Regardless - the `unnest` in `Joined_Q` was the key. Thanks again.

Comment: The only order by that would be unnecessary is the one in Q2, because the array would be unnested and then aggregateted in the last step.

Comment: Oh I see, got it.